# Android Layout Matching Peers

Tags: android, layout, match

I'm looking for some insights into the layout system.  Is anyone aware of a method in the Android layout system that allows **peer** `View` elements (meaning Views grouped together in the same container) to match their height and width attributes without creating an interstitial container just to govern their sizes?

For example: A layout has two `TextView` elements.  The first should always wrap width to its text content, but the second should match the width of the first.  A solution that WORKS is this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textOne"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textTwo"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, I had to create a special container for both views to ensure they both match the width of whatever text is in the first; adding unnecessary complexity to the hierarchy.  What I would love to know is if there is a layout attribute I could use to do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTwo"
    android:layout_widthMatchPeer="@id/textOne" <!-- An attribute like this -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textOne" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Creating a hard dimension as the width is defeating the purpose of letting the primary element wrap.  Is there a technique someone is aware of, or an attribute I've missed, to accomplish this?  Could be in any standard layout, I just chose `RelativeLayout` as an example.

Additionally, what if the elements are not located near each other?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `RelativeLayout` class can do what you want:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTwo"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textOne"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/textOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textOne" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you.  Are you aware of a method to use when the views are not located such that they can share edge coordinates, but simply need to match their size?  Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome! I think there's no general solution for that in Android.

Answer (score 0):

since the views are in a relatve layout, use android:layout_below="id/firsttv" android:layout_alignLeft="id/firsttv" and android:layout_alightRight="id/firsttv"